# Excel plugin that takes values from spreadsheet and calls webservice

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create a plugin that users can install in their instance of Excel. The plugin when invoked would pull values from columns in the spreadsheet, set the values into a webservice and then invoke the webservice. The results from the webservice call would be parsed and entered into other columns in the spreadsheet.

Any help in what direction I should head to get this started would be greatly appreciated. I don't want the answer just some suggestions to get started with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3f8d06eb-4e90-4631-99e6-d6c691aa327e/calling-web-service-from-excel?forum=exceldev) on Microsoft's website.  They highlight this is more of a capability for VBA than a particular product like Excel.

In fact, calling a Web Service from Excel is more related to the feature of VBA language instead of Excel Object Model. We could also do that with the same code in all the applications which support VBA language.

Here is a sample in a same thread for your reference.

> Web Service calls from VBA excel
>
> ```
> Sub http()
>     Dim MyRequest As Object
>     Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
>     MyRequest.Open "GET", "you webservice url"
>     ' Send Request.
>     MyRequest.send
>     'And we get this response
>     MsgBox MyRequest.responseText
> End Sub
> ```
>
> Then you could resort to Excel Object Model to fill the result into
>   the worksheet as you want.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. If I could vote on this answer I would. Exactly what I was looking for to get started!